# IBM WebSphere Portal Server 6 using xmlaccess script to deploy

Tags: xml, websphere-6.1, websphere-portal

I am new on IBM technologies and my company ask me to realize a portlet on an `IBM Websphere Portal Server 6.1` base on `IBM AIX OS`.

I would like to deploy or update my portlet using a script shell. First question, is there a script that can do this ?

If it is `xmlAccess.sh`, i tried this command :

```
/PortalServer/bin/xmlaccess.sh -in deployIL1Portlet.xml -user wasadm -password ********* -url http://localhost:13040/wps/config
```

deployIL1Portlet.xml content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<request
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PortalConfig_6.0.1.xsd" 
    type="update">
    <portal action="locate">
        <web-app action="update" active="true" uid="fr.laposte.disf.il1.portlet.QuizPortlet">
           <url>file:///data1/wasWP61IL1D101N1/il1/il1.war</url>
        </web-app>
    </portal>
</request>
```

I have this error :

```
EJPXB0006I: Connecting to URL http://localhost:13040/wps/config
EJPXB0002I: Reading input file /data1/wasWP61IL1D101N1/profile/PortalServer/bin/deployIL1Portlet.xml
EJPXB0013E: An error occurred while receiving the response.
EJPXB0016E: An error occurred on the client: sun.io.MalformedInputException
```

On IBM Forum i found :
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=205808

So i checked into `wkplc_comp.properties` :
`XmlAccessPort` and `WpsHostPort` equals 13040

If you have some clue, it will be a real help !
Thanks in advance

Comment: The `sun.io.MalformedInputException` suggests that the file is not encoded in UTF-8. I don't see anything suspicious in the posted text, but it would be worth inspecting the file in a hex editor for anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Hi Nicolas try to capture the output in one file by using the follow command:/PortalServer/bin/xmlaccess.sh -in deployIL1Portlet.xml -out \home\wasadm\deployPortlet.xml -user wasadm -password ********* -url http://localhost:13040/wps/config     and share the deployPortlet.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following strategy:

First, install your application through **Administration Console**. Then, once installed, you could export the webapp configuration to generate an XML file that you can use for future updates via **xmlaccess**.